# Perform calculation on my text file with multiple tables in it

Tags: python, dataframe

In my Python code I will be reading the following text file:

```
text = """
Well name:   Well-001
MD in    MD out  SubZones
7556.48523572    7558.27620486   0.000000
7558.27620486    7560.06788752   0.000000
7560.06788752    7561.86037056   0.000000
7561.86037056    7562.69600233   1.000000
7562.69600233    7563.53180593   1.000000
7563.53180593    7564.91478892   2.000000
7564.91478892    7566.29755224   2.000000
7566.29755224    7567.67931936   2.000000
7567.67931936    7568.33927889   3.000000
7568.33927889    7568.99876550   3.000000
7568.99876550    7570.17596547   3.000000
7570.17596547    7571.35355479   2.000000
7571.35355479    7572.53053558   2.000000
7572.53053558    7572.87713383   2.000000
7572.87713383    7573.70951451   3.000000
7573.70951451    7574.35566647   3.000000
7574.35566647    7575.00189268   3.000000
7575.00189268    7576.84445358   3.000000
7576.84445358    7578.68636542   4.000000
7578.68636542    7580.52806605   5.000000
7580.52806605    7582.36868123   6.000000
.
.
.
Well name:   Well-100
MD in    MD out  SubZones
7559.06191603    7560.68722084   0.000000
7560.68722084    7562.31275257   0.000000
7562.31275257    7563.93823559   0.000000
7563.93823559    7564.50391095   1.000000
7564.50391095    7565.06952612   1.000000
7565.06952612    7566.34649406   2.000000
7566.34649406    7567.62333168   2.000000
7567.62333168    7568.90017951   2.000000
7568.90017951    7569.48662623   3.000000
7569.48662623    7570.07350278   3.000000
7570.07350278    7571.72238328   2.000000
7571.72238328    7573.37101460   2.000000
7573.37101460    7575.01990457   3.000000
7575.01990457    7576.66870007   3.000000
7576.66870007    7577.37429322   4.000000
7577.37429322    7578.08009961   5.000000
7578.08009961    7579.61354471   6.000000
7579.61354471    7581.14822056   6.000000
7581.14822056    7582.68365796   6.000000
7582.68365796    7584.21865885   6.000000
.
.
.
"""
```

I want to be able to calculate the footage = MD out - MD in for each well only when SubZones is equal to 3
I want the out put to be a table with the first column to be well name like 'Well-001' and the second column to be the footage of SubZone = 3
Note that the well might enter SubZone=3 multiple times and the total footage should be the sum of all the well footage in SubZone=3
What is the best Python way to code this?

Comment: Extracting structured data from formatted text/HTML/etc. is called [tag:scraping], please see all the existing posts/tutorials/quickstarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to make variable for each data frame but alternately you could make a dictionary where the key is the df name and the value is the dataframe. This code will work though it is super specific to the example you have given.

```
df_dict = dict()
start = None
values_list = []
for i, val in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
#     print(val)
    if len(val) == 0:
        continue
    if val.startswith('Well'):
#         print(values_list)
        df_name = val.split(" ")[-1]
#         print(df_name)
        start = i
        continue
    if val.startswith('MD'):
        values_list = []
        continue
    values = [x for x in val.split(" ") if len(x) != 0]
    values_list.append(values)
    
    if len(values_list) > 1:
        df_dict[df_name] = pd.DataFrame(values_list, columns=['MD in', 'MD out', 'SubZones'])
```

`df_dict` is the dictionary of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

First split the lines of `text` and group them in lists split on the periods, then split the sentences in the lists by double spaces, while stripping the results from trailing spaces. Put in a list comprehension:

```
data = [[[i.strip() for i in x.split("  ") if i] for x in list(g)] for k, g in groupby(text.splitlines()[1:], lambda x: x != ".") if k]
```

This will output:

```
[[['Well name:', 'Well-001'],
  ['MD in', 'MD out', 'SubZones'],
  ['7556.48523572', '7558.27620486', '1.000000'],
  ['7558.27620486', '7560.06788752', '2.000000']],
 [['Well name:', 'Well-100'],
  ['MD in', 'MD out', 'SubZones'],
  ['7556.48523572', '7558.27620486', '1.000000'],
```

You can then create a dict with the well names as keys, and dataframes as values:

```
dataframes = {}
for item in data:
  dataframes[item[0][1]] = pd.DataFrame(item[2:], columns=item[1])
```

You can now access the dataframes by the well names in the dict. `dataframes['Well-001'].head()` will output:

```
|    |   MD in |   MD out |   SubZones |
|---:|--------:|---------:|-----------:|
|  0 | 7556.49 |  7558.28 |          1 |
|  1 | 7558.28 |  7560.07 |          2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed the following answer:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

df_dict = dict()
start = None
values_list = []
footage_list = []
total_footage = 0

comp_files = os.listdir('/content/sample_data/Completion/')

comp_files_list = []

for comp_file in comp_files:
  comp_files_list.append(comp_file)

if '.ipynb_checkpoints' in comp_files_list:
  comp_files_list.remove('.ipynb_checkpoints')

with open('/content/sample_data/Completion/{}'.format(comp_file),'r') as comp_well_file:
  for i, val in enumerate(comp_well_file.read().split('\n')):
    if len(val) == 0:
        continue
    if val.startswith('Well'):
        df_name = val.split(" ")[-1]
        start = i
        continue
    if val.startswith('MD'):
        values_list = []
        continue
    values = [x for x in val.split(" ") if len(x) != 0]
    values_list.append(values)
    if len(values_list) > 1:
        df_dict[df_name] = pd.DataFrame(values_list, columns=['MD in', 'MD out', 'SubZones'])
  columns=['MD in', 'MD out', 'SubZones']
  for key in df_dict.keys():
    for column in columns:
      for row in df_dict[key][column].index:
        if df_dict[key][column][row] == '3.000000':
          footage = float(df_dict[key]['MD out'][row]) - float(df_dict[key]['MD in'][row])
          total_footage =  total_footage + footage
    footage_list.append('{}, {} \n'.format(key,total_footage))
    total_footage = 0
  for i, item in enumerate(footage_list):
    print(item)
  #print(footage_list)
  #print(footage_list[0])
  #df_total_footage = pd.DataFrame(footage_list, columns = ['well_name', 'Total_Footage_in_subzone_of_interest'])
  #print(df_total_footage)
```

and the output will be like:

Well-001, 933.7765628900015

Well-002, 2058.36714124

.
.
.